# Printing whole string with hex escaping, including printable characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
data = Socket.recv(1024) # '\x01\x02\x00' according to debugger
print(data) # prints SQH STX \000
```

print looks like this in terminal:

[image]

I want to print its exact '\x01\x02\x00' without the ASCII

also I'm not sure what characters like "\x01\x02\x00" are   called I think its escaped hex strings?

I've seen online something like this:

```
data = '\x00\x00\x12\x00'

for i in data:

    print hex(ord(i))
```

not quite what I wanted. Anyway to do get the original value outputed?

Comment: print `repr(data)`

Comment: >>> data = '\x83\x02\x00\x5e\x00'


>>> repr(data) 


prints : '\x83\x02\x00^\x00'



Missing x5e and has '^' in its place?

Comment: @sssss Python repr "optimizes" output of hex by replacing it with known characters - f.e. replaces `0x13` with `\n`, `0x10` with `\r` etc. to reduce the amount of printed characters... guess what character `0x5e` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short implementation:

```py
data = '\x00abc'
print(''.join(map('\\x{:02x}'.format, map(ord, data))))
```

Outputs `\x00\x61\x62\x63`

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own custom format based on what hex() returns:

```
def formatit(s):
    """Truncates 0x from the beginning, prepends leading \x or \x0 as needed.
    Produces hex numbers with 2,4,6,8 etc. positions as needed."""
    if len(s)%2 == 0:
        return r"\x"+s[2:]    # 0x8312 -> \x8312
    else:
        return r"\x0"+s[2:]   # 0x831  -> \x0831

byte_s = [0x83, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00]

s = ''.join(formatit(hex(k)) for k in byte_s)
print(s)  # \x83\x02\x00\x00
```

Output:

```
\x83\x02\x00\x00
```

---

If you want it more obstruse, you can go with this one-liner:

```
s = ''.join(r"\x"+ "0"*(len(k)%2) + k[2:] for k in (hex(j) for j in byte_s))
```